# Conditional Extraction of Data from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple DataFrame that looks like:

[image]

```
          Names
0   Alexi Laiho
1   Jari Maenpaa
2   Kirk Hammett
3   Antti Kokko
4   Yngwie Malmsteen
5   Petri Lindroos
```

I want to retrieve records which only have more than 5 vowels in their names.

For this I made function:

```
def vowcount(sentence=[]):
    count=0
    vow='aeiouAEIOU'
    for i in sentence:
        for j in i:
            if j in vow:
                count+=1
    return count
```

How can I use this function to extract records from the DataFrame? 
Please help me to understand how to use df.apply(map()) function on this Pandas Series and how to get the same using list comprehension if possible.

Comment: ok, but please post the data as text [not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Sure anky_91, I added the data in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a simple `regex` statement and using `str.lower`, `str.count` and `.query`:

```
m = df['Names'].str.lower().str.count(r'[aeiou]')
df = df.query('@m > 5')
```

---

Or we can use `re.I` to ignore case:

```
import re

m = df['Names'].str.count(r'[aeiou]', flags = re.I)
df = df.query('@m > 5')
```

**Output**

```
          Names
0   Alexi Laiho
1  Jari Maenpaa
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively with [`findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html):

```
import re
df[df.Names.str.findall('[aeiou]',flags=re.I).str.len().gt(5)]
```

---

```
          Names
0   Alexi Laiho
1  Jari Maenpaa
```